# I can't get my NSTableView updated

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

i have a tableview in my app and i need to update it, but i can't to make it work.
first so it's more clear i post the arraycontroller, the tableview and the code to insert data into my tableview.

First the arraycontroller:

[image: ArrayController]

My tableview:

[image: My tableview1]

[image: Tableview]

[image]

So this is how i configured the tableview and the array controller. To insert data into my tableview i used the keydown method. So when the user press the letter "i" a row is inserted with data.

```
   -(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
  {
       static int i = 1;
      NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
      NSMutableString *str2 = [NSMutableString string];
    [str2 appendString:@"Task "];
   [str2 appendString:str];

if([event keyCode] == 0x22 && projectState == YES)
{




    dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"check",str,@"numero",str2,@"designation",@"1",@"durpr",datedebutProjet,@"debpr",datefin,@"finpr",datedebutProjet,@"debpr1",datefin,@"finpr1",@"0",@"mgt", nil];


    [_arrayController addObject:dict];

    [check setTag:i];


nbrTask = i;
    i++;}
  }
```

I don't have a problem with this but i cannot change the data inside my tableView. I used this to get the data :

```
int Row = [tableView selectedRow];
NSString * designation = [[[_arrayController arrangedObjects]objectAtIndex:Row]valueForKey:@"designation"];
```

and tried to replace it this way:

```
 [[[_arrayController arrangedObjects]objectAtIndex:Row] setValue:finalString forKey:@"designation"];
```

but it didn't work. Then i tried it [tableView reloadData]. But it didn't change anything. No data were modified. Please help me, i'm lost

Comment: Not related but it is **highly** recommended to use **view based** cells. It's so much easier to handle. And use a custom class rather than mutable dictionary. That's much more comfortable – especially in conjunction with array controller – , too.

Comment: Does the data change as expected?

Comment: No it doesn't change at all, that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that objective c accept variables with nil as value. I did a typo later in my code which gave my NSString a nil value, that's why it didn't show anything. Anyway, thank you all for your help!